# Using generics for a class how can I convert the values from one type to another?

Tags: java, generics

I built a simple document store, there are entities that have fields of different types, I have a Float, Int and String type. The entity contains an array list of values, if someone updates the schema of the entity I would like to be able to try to convert the values to the new type.

```
public interface FieldType<T> {
    ArrayList<T> values;
}

public class FloatField implements FieldType<Float> {

}

public class StringField implements FieldType<String> {

}
```

I have thought about using a abstract class with methods as below

```
public abstract class Field<T> implements FieldType<T> {
  abstract public <T> castFromString(String value);
  abstract public <T> castFromFloat(Float value);
  abstract public <T> castFromInt(Int value);
}

public class FloatField extends Field<Float> {
  @override
  public <Float> castFromString(String value){
    Float castValue = null;
    try {
      castValue = Float.parseFloat(value);
    } catch(Exception e){

    }

    return castValue;
  }
}
```

I did not really like this solution as I would have to add a new abstract method each time I added an extra type to the system.

Any ideas how I could implement this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [`Function<T, R>` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)?

```
public abstract class Field<T> implements FieldType<T> {

    ...

    public <F> T convert(F value, Function<F, T> converter) {
        try {
            return converter.apply(value);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

And then specify the converter using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) or a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
field.convert("1234", BigDecimal::new); //with a method reference
field.convert("1234", s -> new BigDecimal(s)) //with a lambda
```

This would replace all of your `convertXXX` methods by one since the return type is inferred from the passed `Function`.

---

EDIT:
If you want automatic converting, you would of course have to hard-code these since you wouldn't want to write conversion methods for all 4240 classes in the Java API. This gets messy, though. Maybe something like this in a static helper class or in `FieldType` itself?

```
public class WhereverYouWantThis {

    private static HashMap<Class<?>, HashMap<Class<?>, Function<?, ?>>> converters = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        putConverter(String.class, Float.class, Float::parseFloat);
    }

    private static <T, R> void putConverter(Class<T> t, Class<R> r, Function<T, R> func) {
        HashMap<Class<?>, Function<?, ?>> map = converters.get(t);
        if(map == null) converters.put(t, map = new HashMap<>());
        map.put(r, func);
    }

    public static <T, R> Function<T, R> getConverter(Class<T> t, Class<R> r) {
        HashMap<Class<?>, Function<?, ?>> map = converters.get(t);
        if(map == null) return null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Function<T, R> func = (Function<T, R>) map.get(r);
        return func;
    }

    public static <T, R> R convert(T o, Class<R> to) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Function<T, R> func = (Function<T, R>) getConverter(o.getClass(), to);
        return func == null ? null : func.apply(o);
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks good, would I have to wrap the return statement in a try catch if it can not be converted to the correct type?

Comment: If you mean when the format is invalid, yes (e.g. `convert("a", Float::parseFloat)`). Fixed that

Comment: Is there any way for FloatField to return the converter, or have a method that could call convert, so I would not have to work out what function to pass?

Comment: @CharlesBryant Added an example. You'll have type warnings but you can `@SuppressWarnings` them _because_ you can prove it's type-safe - the `addConverter` method can only add `Function`s to the map if they have the right type anyway (that is, don't add to the map directly, it's a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need generics for this.  Instead, just try to create a `Float` from the input `String` and return `null` if there be a problem:

```
public Float castFromString(String value) {
    Float castValue = null;
    try {
      castValue = Float.parseFloat(value);
    } catch(Exception e){
        // log here
    }

    return castValue;
}
```

The reason I don't think generics are needed is that the types involved in the conversion are named/known in your helper methods.